# Ruby skip header in spreadsheet gem

Tags: ruby, spreadsheet, xls

I am trying to import some data from Excel XLS spreadsheets.

I have worked only with CSV files before, and know how to skip the first row with them, which is a header.

How to do it with XLS files?

I have this code:

```
require 'spreadsheet'
ook = Spreadsheet.open("/#{Rails.public_path}/uploads_prices/"+name)
book.worksheets.each do |sheet|
      sheet.each do |row|
*****
```

How do I skip the first entry, which is a header?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [doc](http://spreadsheet.rubyforge.org/GUIDE_txt.html): "(...)you can tell Worksheet how many rows should be omitted at the beginning. The following starts at the 3rd row, regardless of whether or not it or the preceding rows contain any data:"

```
sheet2.each 2 do |row|
  # do something interesting with a row
end
```

So for this case the following should work:

```
book.worksheets.each do |sheet|
  sheet.each 1 do |row|
    #...
```

Comment: +1. I gotta say, putting the parameter on `each` isn't intuitive.

Comment: @theTinMan I agree. At least, the docś should state something like : `each(skip_lines = 0)`.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
book.worksheets.each do |sheet|
  sheet[1..-1].each do |row|
    ...
```

Using `[1..-1]` slices the array or enumerable that `sheet.each` would iterate, skipping the first value at `[0]`, returning all the rest.